# What does a Replica ID in Azure Service Fabric really represent?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

What is the significance of the replica id for a stateful service in Azure Service Fabric. To be clear, I understand what a replica is, but I don't understand why a replica in two completely different services would end up with the same ID and/or why for a given service the number of replica IDs is far greater than the TargetReplicaSetSize.

I was trying to identify the replicas that belonged to each partition of a stateful service, and had hoped/assumed the replica id would do that. How could I make this determination?

[image]

To add, given Rotem's guidance below, here is a snapshot of the replicas on one of my nodes. Note the first two lines have the same replica id, but belong to different partitions, that's the part I don't get.

[image]

Similarly, here you see the same replica id used for two different services:

[image]

Clearly, I keep using 'replica id' but that word does not mean what I think it means... what does it mean.

Comment: as for "why for a given service the number of replica IDs is far greater than the TargetReplicaSetSize." I wonder what is the value of "Min Replica Set Size" ?

Comment: target is 3, min is 2, partition count 9... I see the 27 leaf nodes I would expect.

Comment: I added an answer as I cannot add pics in the comments. Plz let us know if this help...

Comment: Well, the first replica is primary while the second one is secondary. hence, different partition scalability...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replica ID uniquely identifies a replica *within* a partition, and only within a partition. You'll notice management operations on replicas require you to specify both a replica ID and a partition ID.

Answer (score 1):

"identify the replicas that belonged to each partition"
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: But I'm seeing a given replica ID applying to more than one partition across multiple services - perhaps replica ID is scoped to a service?

Comment: Interesting too that my UI is different.. I don't see "Deployed" in the title and am not sure how you got to your first screen shot.  I am running this locally, but that should not matter given there (purportedly) is no difference between it running locally and in the cloud.

Comment: What version of the SDK are you running?

Comment: I added another img to show how to get to the "Deployed Replicas"

Comment: Thank you, I found it too.  I've updated my post above to show more clearly where I'm confused.